# Extra folder being added when deploying code to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, image-upload

i'm working on Web APIs. I have configured AWS Elastic Beanstalk in my Visual Studio to deploy code to my server. Yesterday i was stuck in a problem to save images to a folder present on the server out of (as a sibling of) wwwroot of the application. So what i did, for testing purpose, in the below code I gave

```
string subpath = "~/JukesterContent/Images/User";
```

JukesterContent/User is the folder where i wanted to save my image and it present in C/inetpub alongwith wwwroot. When i deployed the code, upon deployment it created another folder named "JukesterWebAPI_deploy" inside the deployment package (which i saw using RDC) and it contains the images I upload. I don't want this now. The code below is the reverted code, cleaned solution, rebuilt it and then deployed but it still creates the folder. How to update this thing?

```
`byte[] contents = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString.Trim('\0'));

            string subpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserImagesFolder"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subpath))
            {
                bool exists = Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(subpath));

                if (!exists)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(subpath));
                }
                string fileName = "Image-" + userId + ".png";
                var savePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(subpath);
                var imagePath = Path.Combine(savePath, Path.GetFileName(fileName));

                if (File.Exists(imagePath))
                {
                    //if a file exists against this user, then delete it, this will be used in update case
                    File.Delete(imagePath);
                }

                using (var imageFile = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    imageFile.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);

                }

                return fileName;
            }`
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you use hosting environment for wwwroot?

Comment: Didn't get you. I'm using AWS Visual Studio plugin for code deployment.